# Entity Framework change database server in database-first approach

Tags: database, entity-framework-6

We have a server machine that host several databases for development and test purpose.

My Entity Framework projects usually use a database-first approach since they are created and administered by someone else.

In some of them I had to rename some relationship.

Now they moved these database to a newer server, thus changing the IP address.
How can I update my projects so they keep the diagrams?

If I change the connection string in web.config, it does connect to the new database, but lose the relationship with the already imported entities.

If I delete and re-import everything I'll have to re-apply all the subtle changes I've made so far.

How can I tell Entity Framework to point to a new server AND that all the already in entities are still the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by manually editing the edmx file.

Close Visual studio and open the edmx file into a text editor.

Change all occurence of Schema="old schema" to Schema="new schema"
Re-open Visual studio.